# Python Rescale/Transform data

Tags: python, transform, rescale

I need to rescale data from a specific range (-120, 14870) to (0, 512). I've been trying different methods but not one seems to be succesful, any ideas how can i get it done?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) and in particular min-max normalization:

```
(x - x.min) / (x.max - x.min) * 512
```